# Why its adding version_no in js and css url in magento2?

Tags: magento2, css, version

On my local system I am setting up an project. All setup done and its not showing any error. But its not picking css/js.

I run the following commands but no one making effect to work -

> sudo chmod -R 0777 var
>   sudo chmod -R 0777 pub
>   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>   php bin/magento cache:flush
>   php bin/magento indexer:reindex

As I see the view source its adding versionNumber in url like -

> pub/static/version1487053472/frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme/en_US/mage/calendar.css

and its showing 404 when I hit the url for respective css/js. And As I am checking respective css/js file to respective location without version1487053472, its available .

I am stuck ryt now, how to fix it. Please do a reply if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Are you using Apache or nginx? It could be that you are missing the required rewrite rules for signed version files to work.

Comment: `core_config_data` check for web url

Comment: @DannyNimmo - I am using Apache, are saying about mod_rewrite its showing "Module rewrite already enabled"

Comment: You should check that you have the `.htaccess` file in the `pub/static` directory: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.4/pub/static/.htaccess

This will add the rewrite for version URLS. Versions are for cachebusting static assets, you can read about cachebusting here: https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to turn off configuration option from backend.

**Stores>Configuration>Advanced>Developer>Sign Static Files** select **No**.

Save Config. Now check frontend version number will not display anymore in URLs.

Moreover you need to check .htaccess file in **magento_root/pub/static**, if it is not present please copy it from github. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess

Comment: Admin login page also not picking css. And once I made login below erros come  -    3 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\Role\GroupFactory does not exist
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\Role\GroupFactory does not exist
Exception #2 (RuntimeException): Can't create directory /var/www/html/git_projects/csep/var/generation/Magento/Authorization/Model/Acl/Role/.

Comment: this works for me -  in table 'core_config_data' setted 'dev/static/sign' to 0, then flush the cache using - php bin/magento cache:flush and its works now .
Thanks Salma

Comment: But still have question - Why its adding version-number ?whats the roll of it ?

Comment: Adding a digital signature to the URL of static files makes it possible for browsers to detect when a newer version of the file is available. If you have enabled browser caching it will help to detect newer version.

Comment: Wasting like 4 hours. this answer helped me. Thanks :)

Comment: i fallow your instruction but its not working for me

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari Did you clear cache after applying the settings?

Comment: Yes after setting i have flushed cache clean, deploy everything but its not working for me

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari Please try this - In table 'core_config_data' setted 'dev/static/sign' to 0, then flush the cache using - php bin/magento cache:flush and its works now

Comment: ```Please try this - In table 'core_config_data' setted 'dev/static/sign' to 0, then flush the cache using - php bin/magento cache:flush and its works now``` helped me

Answer (score 1):

This should actually not lead to a 404 error - you should check your `.htaccess` in pub/static/ - did you maybe accidentially delete it?

As Salma Saiyad points out in the other answer's comment, this is a actually feature - to use updated files despite of the browser cache on deploys.

Comment: thx Alex for clarification............ :)